# How to fix Corrupted BIOS (Dell Inspiron 3467 7th gen laptop)

Tags: bios, corrupt

After updating bios.It corrupted! Now when I try to start my laptop it takes about 2 min to show the boot loader. It seems like my bios is corrupted. I have watched many videos and read many blogs but I cant solve this problem. Because, I cant extract the driver BIOS of my laptop.It tells this file cant be extract. If it can be extracted then i can fix the problem. But i cant extract the executable file.So, anyone give me any solution please!!